# Debian 10 and 11 not detecting WiFi adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

I have just installed Debian 10 and it does not seem to detect my WiFi adapter from TP-Link, called TP-WN725N. So I tried to upgrade to Debian 11, but it still does not seem to detect this adapter at all.

I have installed `r8168-dkms`, but that does not do a difference.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:0819 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C210
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046a:b090 Cherry GmbH Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c542 Logitech, Inc. Wireless Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I am not exactly sure what `Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub`. It may be my WiFi adapter, but that is not what it is called.

I believe this is a driver issue. It has previously worked well on Arch Linux.

Comment: What’s the adapter’s exact make and model? How did you determine neither `lspci` nor `lsusb` shows your adapter? Keep in mind that the adapter is *either* PCIe *or* USB but never both.

Comment: So from your updated question I see it’s a USB device. Please provide the output of `lsusb`. Because it is not a PCIe device, `lspci` is completely irrelevant. Drivers are also (largely) unrelated to what shows up with `lsusb`.

Comment: Didn’t see you added the output, sorry. // Try a different USB port, preferably one on the back of your PC (direct motherboard connection). Your Wi-Fi adapter could simply have died. It happens.

Comment: That does not seem to fix the issue. I am not exactly sire what you mean by my WiFi adapter could have died. If your trying to say it may not work, it does work. I tried it on a different computer, with Arch Linux, it worked.